# How can I check if client exists in database before inserting data into database in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

A little assistance on how I can check if client already exists in the database before adding him or her into the database using a for loop in ASP.NET Core Web API.

I have a list of clients and I'm are trying to insert them into the database, but before I do that, I want to check if that client already exists. I am stuck here on how to do it - please help

This is my code:

```
foreach (Client client in clientList)  
{
    await _dbconnection.clients.AddAsync(client);  
}  

await _dbconnection.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: What is `_dbconnection`? Is it an Entity Framework DbContext?

Comment: you could select Count(*) where username = client.username, client.email or whatever you are using for login for example.  if greater than 1 they exist

Comment: yes _dbconnection is an entity framework DbContext

Comment: `I want to check if that client already exists` which property you want to check for Client? The client class should have many properties and which one you want to judge if it exists? e.g. client contains Email and address property and you want to judge if Email in duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
foreach (Client client in clientList)  
{
   var exist= await _dbconnection.clients.Any(x=> x.Id==client.Id)
    if (!exist) _dbconnection.clients.Add(client);  
}  

await _dbconnection.SaveChangesAsync();
```